# How to mute the music of youtube video if any claim is raised against it using youtube data api v3

Tags: python-3.x, youtube, youtube-data-api, google-api-client

To resolve copyright issue raise against any video.
Currently, i'm calling the video list api and seeing the contentdetails if any video licensedContent value is coming True. I have to find why this video is licensedContent if it's related to music claim then i want to mute the music for particular time duration. But haven't found any api to do it.
Any youtube api is available for this to resolve this issues.